# Ruby array intersection returning a blank array

Tags: arrays, ruby, intersection

I'm very new to Ruby so please go easy on me.  I have this small function that doesn't want to perform an intersection command.  If I go into irb and enter the arrays then set the intersection command like: third_array = array1 & array2, third_array returns the common element.  But when I run this snippet through irb, it just returns [ ].  Any suggestions?

```
class String

  define_method(:antigrams) do |word2|

    array1 = []
    array2 = []
    array1.push(self.split(""))
    array2.push(word2.split(""))
    third_array = array1 & array2
      third_array
  end

end
```

Comment: There's no need to use `define_method` here when `def` would do the job. `define_method` is reserved for cases where you don't know the name of the method in advance, it's computed, or the block inside is generated dynamically somehow.

Comment: G McMahon, are you by any change taking a course where `define_method` is introduced before `def` (i.e., `def antigrams(word2)`)? I ask because, as @tadman mentions, using `define_method` here is a bit odd, but I could see where an instructor might believe it's useful to cover `define_method` before `def`.

Comment: Yes Cary, that is the case.  I've seen 'def' used but haven't really used it myself.  Maybe in my second week!?

Comment: `define_method` is intended for meta-programming, that is code that writes code, so dropping that people on week one is really throwing them into the deep end. Every introduction I've ever seen or written *always* starts with `def`.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at what you have, I think your code boils down to this:

```
class String
  def antigrams(word)
    self.chars & word.chars
  end
end

"flurry".antigrams("flagrant")
# => ["f", "l", "r"]
```

If you're calling `split('')` on a word that's effectively the same as `chars`, though a lot less efficient. Another mistake was pushing a whole array into an array, which creates a nested array of the form `[ [ 'f', 'l', ... ] ]`. Since the two resulting array-of-arrays have nothing in common, their inner arrays are different, the `&` operation returns an empty array.

What you meant was to concatenate the one array to the other, something that can be done with `+=` for example.

Whenever you're curious what's happening, either use `irb` to try out chunks of code, or `p` to debug at different points in your method.

Comment: That is great!  Thank you!  +1 but it's not publicly recorded...too new :)